# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following script inside my asp.net mvc 5 web project:-

```
$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
    var target = $(this);
    target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000 });

});
```

but i am getting the following exception :-

```
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'
```

so can anyone advice what might be causing this error ?
Thank

**Edit**
Inside my _layout view i have the following:-

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and on the view that is raising the error i define the following:-

```
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/Custome.js"></script>}
```

where the cusotm.js contains my above auto complete code. i have noted another problem is that i have Ajax.BeginForm on my view, but it is working as normal form , and it is not generating Ajax requests, although i am loading the ~/bundles/jqueryval ? can you adivce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the `.autocomplete()` method, then that is probably because you don't have the right jQuery plugins loaded that contain that method.

If you intend to be using the autocomplete method from the jQuery UI set of plugins, then you need to load that library before you can use this method.

Comment: yes i want to use the jQuery UI set of plugins , and they are loaded succfully

Comment: @johnG - the fact that `.autocomplete()` does not exist means that something did not load correctly.  You may need to check for loading errors and make sure nothing is being loaded async or defer.

Comment: @johnG - I think I'd have to see the rendered HTML page to see what it was actually loading (since I don't know what is in any of those scripts or how the asp logic works in them.  Also, which of those scripts is supposedly loading the autocomplete plugin?

Comment: custome.js will load the auto complete code , and it will fire after rendering the body and the jQuery files

Comment: @johnG - there's too much framework stuff in the way for me to tell what's really going to happen in your page or what errors are causing you problems without seeing the actual page in a browser.  If you want to post a link to a live page with all this code installed that illustrates the problem, we could take a look at the actual page.

Comment: i was missing the jQuery Ui scripts & CSS , i download them and i added them to my project and now the auto complete is working.